Release an app to the Windows Store but have it only available to employees of my company
I created an app for fellow employees of our company. It’s not to be used by people outside our company.  I also want to deploy it to the Windows Store because it will be frequently updated and I want my colleagues to have the latest version.
Will the Windows Store allow me to do this?
I’ve done some research and there is such thing as Private apps but it says it’s part of a business/education account that will soon be deprecated. Even if this feature is available in some other form, my understanding is that my app will still be listed in the Windows Store where others can find it.  I think the ability to make an app “private” means that it can be added to my company’s MS Company Portal but, as I already mentioned, I still think it’s discoverable in the store by the general public.
Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks.
